# Non-x86 CI service

Tags: java, continuous-integration, arm, scala

Please suggest CI service that can run Java/Scala builds with tests on non-x86 architectures: ARM, PowerPC etc. Maven (or Sbt) integration is required. Free option for OSS projects (like in Travis-CI or Shippable) is highly desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Service or software?
For software i've written something that is cross platform.

http://linci.tp23.org/ is written basically in bash. Its reuses existing Linux tools to cobble together a CI server.
`ssh` for remoting, `tsp` for task scheduling, `cron` for timers, `bash` and `awk` to define jobs and the CLI to execute them.  `ii`(irc) , `xtomp` or `mailx` for notifications.

I run it on x86 and raspberry pi (ARM),  I think it will run on anything for which you can find a Debian based Linux distro.  Linux only.

Plugins are sets of env variables: you define an environment for a build e.g. you could define `java8` and `java9` with different `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` and to exec maven linci can call maven's cli.  It does not need a plugin for each tool provided the tool has a CLI.

UI is cli/terminal, with bash_completion.

vcs triggers, i.e. run build on submit, use the vvcs buidlint hooks, git hooks, svn perforce triggers and bzr python hook.

Webhooks use a nodejs server, but would be trivial to write webhooks on a different platform.